# Are there any alternatives to the `find` command on linux for SunOS?

Tags: shell-script, find, solaris

The `find` command on Linux has a lot of options compared to the `find` command on SunOS or Solaris.

I want to use the `find` command like this:

```
find data/ -type f -name "temp*" -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %f\n" | sort -r
```

It works perfectly fine on a Linux machine, but the same command doesn't have the option `-printf` on a SunOS machine. I want to customize my output in the `"%TY-%Tm-%Td %f\n"` format.

Please suggest any alternatives for SunOS.

Comment: To use GNU `find` on Solaris, install the [findutils](https://www.opencsw.org/packages/findutils/) package.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Note that it has nothing to do with Linux; that `-printf` predicate is specific to the GNU implementation of `find`. Linux is not an OS, it's just the kernel found in a number of OSes. While most of those OSes used to use a GNU userland in the past, now the great majority of OSes using Linux are embedded and have basic commands if they have any.

The GNU `find` command, which predates Linux, can be installed on most Unix-like OSes. It was certainly used on Solaris (called SunOS back then) before Linux came out.

Nowadays, it's even available as an Oracle package for Solaris. On Solaris 11, that's in `file/gnu-findutils`, and the command is named `gfind` (for GNU `find`, to distinguish it from the system's own `find` command).

Now, if you can't install packages, your best bet is probably to use `perl`:

```
find data/ -type f -name "temp*" -exec perl -MPOSIX -le '
  for (@ARGV) {
    unless(@s = lstat($_)) {
      warn "$_: $!\n";
      next;
    }
    print strftime("%Y-%m-%d", localtime($s[9])) . " $_";
  }' {} + | sort -r
```

Here, we're still using `find` (Solaris implementation) to find the files, but we're using its `-exec` predicate to pass the list of files to `perl`. And `perl` does a `lstat()` on each to retrieve the file metadata (including the modification time as the 10th element (`$s[9]`)), interprets it in the local timezone (`localtime()`) and formats it (`strftime()`) which it then `print`s alongside the file name (`$_` is the loop variable if none is specified in `perl`, and `$!` is the equivalent of `stderror(errno)`, the error text for the last system call failure).

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if the GNU people did look at existing standards before implementing enhancements? There is already a standard on how to use a format to specify `ls` type output, see List mode specification in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html

Comment: @schily, GNU `find`'s `-printf` predates POSIX.2, so the POSIX folks are to blame here. Also note that the POSIX spec wasn't public until the 2000s. I'd still blame the GNU folks for introducing their `stat` over a decade later with a different and inferior syntax for its format specification.

Comment: Could you mention when GNU find did add that feature? Since Solaris pax supports this list mode since 1998, I guess it has been introduced with SUSv2.

Comment: You could also simply install a gnu find in your own bin directory and set the path to search that before the canonical directories.

Comment: @schily, the earliest version of GNU find I have is 3.1 from 1991, it already had -printf (3.1 added the %k format directive), the changelog doesn't mention when it was added, possibly it was there from the start. The ChangeLog goes back to 1987.

Comment: We still need to blame the GNU people for not collaborating with the standard commitee.  There are few cases where the standard commitee did something wrong: 1) introducing `getpgrp()/setpgrp()` incompatible to BSD 2) introducing Dreppers `fgetline()` and `fexec()` even though it is in conflict with older published UNIX distros (in that case UNOS).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach it is with the `find2perl` script, which converts (here, a subset) of a `find` command to a corresponding perl script. The perl script uses a the `File::Find` module to do the heavy lifting. Because the find2perl script on my system didn't support the `-printf` predicate, I added it in manually:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use File::Find ();

use vars qw/*name *dir *prune/;
*name   = *File::Find::name;
*dir    = *File::Find::dir;
*prune  = *File::Find::prune;

sub wanted {
    my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid, $mtime, $year, $month, $day);

    if ((($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,undef,undef,undef,$mtime) = lstat($_)) &&
    -f _ &&
    /^temp.*\z/s) {
        (undef, undef, undef, $day, $month, $year) = localtime($mtime);
        $year += 1900;
        $month++;
        printf "%d-%d-%d %s\n", $year, $month, $day, $_;
    }
}

File::Find::find({wanted => \&wanted}, 'data/');
exit;
```

On two sample files that I created, the output is the same:

```
$ tree data
data
├── subdir
│   └── foo
│       └── temp2
└── temp1

2 directories, 2 files

$ touch -d 2018-06-20 data/subdir/foo/temp2
$ touch -d 2018-05-19 data/temp1

$ find data/ -type f -name "temp*" -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %f\n" | sort -r
2018-06-20 temp2
2018-05-19 temp1

$ ./perlfind | sort -r
2018-06-20 temp2
2018-05-19 temp1
```